# regionDidChange called several times on app load

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I have noticed that as the app is first loaded the regionDidChange method is called a couple times before loading the map (or as the map is loading)

In order to avoid this behaviour, I had to use the following hack so the the logic that I store within regionWillChange is only called once

```
if(self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta !=0 )
```

Is there a non-hack way to avoid regionDidChange to be called by the system before the map is properly loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `– mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:` to set a flag `mapHasLoaded`?

```
- mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {
    self.mapHasLoaded = YES;
}
```

So you can modify your if statement, like this

```
if(self.mapHasLoaded)
```